# How to display precise value on tooltip on moving a cursor in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am working with high charts. My requirement is to show data as the user hover on a particular point but high charts default behavior is something different. As shown in code snippet when I hover from one point to another the value of tool tip changes in the mid way. I want when cursor arrives at the point it should change the value not in the mid way of two points.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 0.1
        
    },

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
         backgroundColor: 'white',
            positioner: function () {
                return {
                    x: this.chart.plotLeft,
                    y: this.chart.plotTop
                }
            },
    },
  

    series: [{
        data: [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
        step: 'left'
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `snap` option of the tooltip and set its value to be -1. And also set the `stickyTracking` to `false`. This will allow the hover event to be captured only when the mouse pointer is hovered exactly over a particular point and does not fire the hover event to display tooltip midway between two points.

You can adjust the `snap` value to define starting from where does the tooltip need to be shown for a point. By default, it is `10px`. That is, when the mouse enters a 10px radius around the point, the tooltip will be shown.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minorTickInterval: 0.1
        
    },

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        snap: -1,
        hideDelay: 5000,
         backgroundColor: 'white',
            positioner: function () {
                return {
                    x: this.chart.plotLeft,
                    y: this.chart.plotTop
                }
            },
    },
    
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stickyTracking: false
        }
    },
  

    series: [{
        data: [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
        step: 'left'
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.snap
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stickyTracking

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, samuellawrentz. thanks for reply. But I want the tooltip to stay as long as it don't reaches the next point. In this example tooltip get disappeared after I hover mouse away from the point. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @SUKH You could increase `hideDelay` to increase the time for which the tooltip is shown. I have edited the answer.